# Calculating This Peculiar Curve Integral

Tags: calculus, integration, curves

Take $\gamma$ to be a curve with parametric representation
$$\phi(t) = (e^t \sin(2t),e^t \cos(t)), t \in [0,2\pi].$$

I would like to find the length of $\gamma$. I believe that the length of
$\gamma$ is
$$L(\gamma) = \int_0^{2\pi} \| \phi'(t)\| dt
= \int_0^{2\pi} \|(2e^t \cos(2t) + e^t \sin(2t),-e^t\sin(t) + e^t\cos(t))\| dt$$
$$=\int_0^{2\pi} \sqrt{(2e^t \cos(2t) + e^t \sin(2t))^2
+ (-e^t\sin(t) + e^t\cos(t))^2} dt,$$

Althought this is beginning to become unweildy and I am not entirely sure how
to continue with this calculation. Wolfram also seems to be having difficulty
with figuring out this integral. Any recommendations on how to find
$L(\gamma)$?

Comment: Numerical integration. (Looks harder than a complete elliptic integral of the second kind.)

Comment: Did you write the problem correctly? If you change $\sin(2t)$ to $\sin(t)$ or $\cos(t)$ to $\cos(2t)$ in your definition of $\phi$, it will get much simpler.